# Python - pool.starmap() running much slower than pool.map()

Tags: python, dictionary, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, starmap

To clarify first of all, I'm **NOT** asking why map in multiprocessing is slow.
I had code working just fine using `pool.map()`. But, in developing it (and to make it more generic), I needed to use `pool.starmap()` to pass 2 arguments instead of one.
I'm still fairly new to Python and multiprocessing, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something obviously wrong here. I also couldn't find anything on this that's been previously asked, so apologies if this has already been answered.
**Using python 3.10 by the way.**

I'm processing just under 5 million items in a list, and managed to get a result in just over 12 minutes (instead of a predicted 6 1/2 days if it was run iteratively!) when using `pool.map()`.
I'm essentially obtaining the intersection of `List_A` and `List_B`, but I need to preserve the frequencies of each item, and so have to do it in O(n^m).

But now, I'm getting significantly longer times when using `pool.starmap()`.
I can't seem to work out why, and if anyone can give me some indiciation it would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code for `pool.map()` that works quickly as expected (where `List_B` is actually part of the `listCompare` function:

```
def listCompare(list_A):
    toReturn = []
    for item in list_A:
        if item in list_B:
            toReturn.append(item)
    return toReturn

out = []
chnks = chunks(list_a, multiprocessing.cpu_count())
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    for result in pool.map(listCompare, chnks):
        out.extend(result)            
print("Parallel:", out)
```

Here is the code for `pool.starmap()` that works slowly. `listCompare` is modified to take 2 arguments here:
*(I can't use my `chunks` method here, as I can't pass the yeild into the tuple, so I've set the chunksize differently. Is this the reason for the slow down?)*

```
def listCompare(list_A, list_B):
    toReturn = []
    for item in list_A:
        if item in list_B:
            toReturn.append(item)
    return toReturn

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    for resultA in pool.starmap(listCompare, [(list_a1, list_b1)], chunksize=multiprocessing.cpu_count()):
        output_list1.extend(resultA)
    for resultB in pool.starmap(listCompare, [(list_a2, list_b2)], chunksize=multiprocessing.cpu_count()):
        output_list2.extend(resultB)
    for resultC in pool.starmap(listCompare, [(list_a3, list_b3)], chunksize=multiprocessing.cpu_count()):
        output_list3.extend(resultC)
    for resultD in pool.starmap(listCompare, [(list_a4, list_b4)], chunksize=multiprocessing.cpu_count()):
        output_list4.extend(resultD)
```

Thanks in advance, and apologies if I've missed out anything that may help in answering!
As I said earlier, I know this can be done with `intersection`, but I need the frequencies of each occurance, so I need to preserve duplicates.

Comment: Your example does not seem equivalent for map and starmap. What is `list_a1..._a4` and `list_b1...b4`? Are they subsections of `list_a` and `list_b`, in which case why have you divided the lists in the first place (on top using chunks) in the starmap approach?

Comment: `pool.starMap(listCompare, [(list_a1, list_b1)], ...)` starts exactly one process and waits for the result.  Then you're starting a second process and waiting for the result.  Obviously you're not getting any multiprocessing happening here.

Comment: @Charchit The starmap version allows me to pass different lists. They’re not subsections, just poorly named variables in this example I guess.

Comment: @FrankYellin I don’t understand how pool.starmap isn’t multiprocessing based on the chunksize parameter?

Comment: @Kav the chunksize is used divide the size of the iterable each process gets passed in one go. Here the size of the iterable is already 1 (you are passing a list of length one containing a tuple), so the chunk parameter could very well be omitted as its not doing anything.

Comment: @Charchit Ah yes. I think I’ve got confused with my own chunk method and trying to work around not being able to use it in starmap.

Comment: @Kav.  pool.starmap expects a list of tuples.  Each tuple is the arguments you're calling the function with.  In your code, you're calling it with `[(list_a1, list_b2)]`, a list with length 1, containing a single tuple of length 2.  You are calling your function once.

Comment: @FrankYellin Ah, I see. So, if I need to compare list_a and list_b, then compare list_c and list_d, then compare list_e and list_f, and so on… is there a way to do that with starmap? Otherwise I’d have to do it with map but hardcode the second lists into the listCompare method which I’d like to avoid.

Comment: "I'm essentially obtaining the intersection of List_A and List_B, but I need to preserve the frequencies of each item, and so have to do it in O(n^m)." What **exactly** are you doing? Why does it have to be O(N^M)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the speed is slow here because you are passing the whole iterable to a single process (as the argument length is one), rather than spread it over multiple processes.

I would recommend to keep using map here, using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to fix argument containing `list_B`, when passing the target function:

```
from functools import partial

def listCompare(list_B, list_A):
    toReturn = []
    for item in list_A:
        if item in list_B:
            toReturn.append(item)
    return toReturn


with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    for resultA in pool.map(partial(listCompare, list_b1), list_a1, chunksize=len(list_a1//multiprocessing.cpu_count())):
        output_list1.extend(resultA)
```

Keep in mind that the order of the keyword arguments has been swapped in `listCompare` for this to work (`list_B` comes before `list_A`). The chunking is then done using `chunksize` parameter (admittedly, a very crude version of it, you may want to fine tune it).

Alternatively, if you want to use starmap, then you may keep using your `chunk`  method like below:

```
def listCompare(list_A, list_B):
    toReturn = []
    for item in list_A:
        if item in list_B:
            toReturn.append(item)
    return toReturn

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    chunks = chunk(list_a, multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    for resultA in pool.starmap(listCompare, [(c, list_b1) for c in chunks]):
        output_list1.extend(resultA)
```

Since you already have chunked the iterable on your own, you no longer need to pass a `chunksize` argument.

As a sidenote, if the iterable you pass to the pool is too long, you may want to use [`imap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) instead to lazily iterate rather than storing the whole iterable in memory.

Comment: [(c, list_b1) for c in chunks]

This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!